# How to do branching in Team Foundation Services After every major production release

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I am very new to Team Foundation Services(free by MS). I have created this structure of my source code and it served well so far.
[My source code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyXoo.jpg)

I want to understand how to create various branches so that when I do a major release on production I can separate & secure the source code so far in a branch, create a new branch and start working on it for next phase . Something like

Fit***

1. Phase 1
2. Phase 2
3. Phase 2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to know the steps to create a branch?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Yes, in the form of structure as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TFVC as your source control. There are built-in branching and merging features in TFS. You can achieve this from GUI directly or [use Team Foundation version control commands](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands) . More detail info you from MSDN for your reference: [Use branches to isolate risk in Team Foundation Version Control](http://Use%20branches%20to%20isolate%20risk%20in%20Team%20Foundation%20Version%20Control)

If you are using GIT as your souce control, it's the same. You can use Git command and you can also create it in Team Explorer by following this: [Create work in branches](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/branches)

If you meaning you just want to choose a branching strategy for releases. You can

> Option A. Just using mainline and tagging for release
>
> Option B. Branch
>   by release
>
> Option C. Crazy Bonus Option

Details, please refer the  answer from *Keith Brings* in this question: [Choosing the right branching strategy for releases](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131171/choosing-the-right-branching-strategy-for-releases)

Comment: Thanks !! I will look into the link and see if they help me. I will get back on this.